# Visual Studio is not recognized by unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

This might seem really simple and dumb... but does any have the same issue i download visual studio but it still not grey like the others... don't get me wrong visual studio works fine but it just concerns me a little bit Thank for your help in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A1e8.png)

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: the unity hub says that vs is not installed but it is installed actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the check mark is blue in your screenshot because the Visual Studio option is selected for install but has not been installed. You should click the 'Next' button and install the Visual Studio tools module in Unity.

The grey check boxes are grey because they are already installed modules.

Get started with Visual Studio Tools for Unity

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2019